# Print Unicode characters by code

Tags: c, unicode, utf-8

I have an array of `uint32_t`. Each is value representing a Unicode characters. I want to print the array like a string but I'm not able to get that working.

I tried a lot of different things

```
typedef struct String {
    uint32_t *characters;
    unsigned long length;
} WRString;

char* WRStringToString(WRString *wstr){
    char *string = malloc(sizeof(char) * wstr->length * 4);
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for (; i < wstr->length; i++) {
        string[j++] = wstr->characters[i];

        char byte2 = (char)wstr->characters[i] >> 8;
        if (byte2) {
            string[j++] = byte2;

            char byte3 = (char)wstr->characters[i] >> 16;
            if (byte3) {
                string[j++] = byte3;

                char byte4 = (char)wstr->characters[i] >> 24;
                if (byte4) {
                    string[j++] = byte4;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return string;
}
```

Always with

```
WRString *string; //Characters are 0xD6, 0x73, 0x74, 0x65, 0x72, 0x72, 0x65, 0x69, 0x63, 0x68
```

I tried:

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"de_DE.UTF-8");
puts(WRStringToString(string));
```

Gives `\326\377\377\377sterreich`.

```
wprintf(L"%s",WRStringToString(string));
```

Gives the same as long as no local is set.

[Printing UTF-8 strings with printf - wide vs. multibyte string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528359/printing-utf-8-strings-with-printf-wide-vs-multibyte-string-literals) and [Printing Unicode Character (stored in variables) in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12017342/printing-unicode-character-stored-in-variables-in-c) do not really help me.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Those aren't UTF-8 characters in the string, or you could just print them directly. They're Unicode codepoints. Please keep your terminology straight.

Comment: @MarkRansom, no, he seems to have just the utf8 bytes encoded in his `uint32_t`

Comment: There are so many terminology problems in the question that it's unclear what you're asking.  I can't tell if it's just a language problem or if there's a misunderstanding with regard to Unicode concepts like UTF-8, characters, etc.

Comment: @JensGustedt No, the first character in his example is 0xD6, which is the codepoint for `Ö`. I doubt it's a legitimate UTF-8 sequence.

Comment: @MarkRansom, ok, yes, so then (s)he is really confused.

Comment: @JensGustedt Am I confused? Please could you tell me what I mixed?

Comment: @idmean, you are taking unicode code points for utf8 encoding. this is not at all the same thing.

Comment: @JensGustedt Oh yes, I see. UTF8 are only Unicode code points that are encoded into up to 4 bytes, aren't they?

Comment: @idmean, sort of, there is really a non-trivial encoding procedure, which you probably don't want to code yourself. Just use the C library as of my answer.

Comment: Note operator precedence: cast beats shift.  `(char)wstr->characters[i] >> 8` --> `((char)wstr->characters[i]) >> 8`.  Certain OP wants `(char) (wstr->characters[i] >> 8)`.  There are other issues too.

Comment: @chux Thanks for pointing that out. What other issues do you mean?

Comment: Other issues: "0xD6, 0x73, 0x74, 0x65,..." is certainly not UTF8, yet locale is `"de_DE.UTF-8"`.  Minor: why use `unsigned long length` instead of `size_t` or `unsigned`? Should use `wstr->length * sizeof(uint32_t) + 1` instead of `sizeof(char) * wstr->length * 4`.  `string` is not null character terminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jens Gustedt's answer was a point into the right direction but I keep using `uint32_t`, because I need to support Unicode's Emojis and `wchar_t` can be too small for those. (as said above by Remy Lebeau)

This seems to be working perfectly fine:

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"de_DE.UTF-8");
printf("%ls\n", string->characters);
```

Comment: No, it only seems so. In exactly the case that `wchar_t` is only 16 bit this will explode under your feet. A platform that has 16 bit `wchar_t` simply can't handle Emojis and stuff like that.

Comment: @JensGustedt Yes, I'm aware of that. But I'll stick to `uint32_t` because a lot of the other code used in the project is already using `uint32_t`. Even on a system on which I can't print using the above method, I'll be at least able to do the other comparisons I need to do. (The unicode code points for emojis are *very* important)

Comment: But then be sure to buildin something that inhibits compilation on a machine with 16 bit `wchar_t`. Just passing the wrong pointer type to `printf` is a time bomb.

Comment: @JensGustedt Thanks for the adivce. I planned to do something like this.

Answer (score 2):

Theses just seem to be unicode code points. Store them in a `wchar_t` string, one by one, and then print this with

```
printf("%ls\n", wstring);
```

You'd have to set the locale right at the start of your program to the default of the system:

```
set_locale(LC_ALL, "");
```

Comment: According to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character#Programming_specifics) wchar_t can be as small as one byte. So it seems not perfect.

Comment: I can't see anything running `wchar_t l[11] = {0x1F330, 0xD6, 0x73, 0x74, 0x65, 0x72, 0x72, 0x65, 0x69, 0x63, 0x68};
printf("%ls\n", l);` Did I again mix something?

Comment: did you set the locale to something utf8? The C (default) locale wouldn't handle these characters.

Comment: I tried with and without `setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"de_DE.UTF-8");`

Comment: And no, on any reasonable platforms `wchar_t` is at least 16 bit nowadays. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: also you forgot the `0` character at the endof your string. An alternative would just be to use a normal string `char s[] = "Östereich"` should work out of the box if you are using the correct locale.

Comment: Ah yes, it was just the 0 character. Thanks. I can't use a char array for good reasons.

Comment: `wchar_t` is 16-bit on some platforms, like Windows, and thus can be used for UTF-16 encoding, whereas it is 32bit on other platforms, and thus can be used for UTF-32 encoding instead. You have to take encoding into account when converting `uint32_t` values (which are presumably holding raw Unicode codepoints) to `wchar_t` strings (which must be UTF encoded). This discrepancy is why modern C++ now has standard `char16_t` (UTF-16) and `char32_t` (UTF-32) types. Best to use an existing Unicode library, if not native C++ functionality.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I know, but the use of code points outside the 16 bit range is extremely rare. For most everyday coding needs `wchar_t` is completely sufficient. BTW, C11 has the same new 16 bit and 32 character types. Unfortunately there does not come much functionality with it, so they are mainly useless.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Rare, but not impossible. The SMP plane in particular (U+10000 –​ U+1FFFF) contains some useful codepoints, like musical and mathematical symbols, and emoji symbols (which are gaining popularity in chat/IM systems). Clearly those do not fit in 16bits without the use of UTF-16 surrogates.