# C Strings With Chars Like 'é' or 'ç'

Tags: unicode, dev-c++

Im using Dev - C++, and developing some software for myself in my language, every string that i type can't have chars like 'é' or 'ã' and 'ç' don't show 'ç'. But in my native language they are all necessary characters to build words. What i need to do in this IDE or in the code to bring this chars to the screen? Any help, thanks.

When i do the Execute -> Compile & Run . of:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
char *text = "é á ç â\n";
fprintf(stdout,text);
return 0;}
```

i get:

[image]

note: i intend to continue to do code in this IDE. i use others but this questions is for users of this IDE.

Comment: Are they ascii characters? If so whilst they won't display in the IDE they will most likely display in the UI fine.

Comment: i do the typing of them in the printf func. And when i compile and run i see them like symbols in the IDE window.

Comment: If they are unicode then it works differently, see this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12017342/printing-unicode-character-stored-in-variables-in-c

Comment: Another good question on the topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007261/why-doesnt-printf-format-unicode-parameters

Comment: "Bring the chars to the screen" is a bit broad. What do you want to do exactly? Print characters to the console? On which OS?